# XCode: Can you install runtimes for iOS versions that aren't listed by default?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, emulation

I want to install a simulator in XCode for an iPhone 7 running iOS 14.7.1. I went to `Xcode` -> `Preferences` -> `Components` and saw the following list that I could download runtimes from. It doesn't include 14.7. Is it possible to get runtimes for iOS versions that aren't in this list?

[image]

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Comment: @alvAro365 Thanks for the link. I downloaded the runtime I wanted and put it in the same directory on my computer as all the existing ones, but it still doesn't show up in the list in the screenshot shown in my post. I re-started Xcode and everything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer version, like me, the `components` are now called `Platforms`, and you have a plus button at the bottom of the screen to download more by the desired platform:
[image]

[image]